# Q: Jssor account for body padding in Scalewidth

Tags: jquery, slider, jssor, calc

I am running into some responsive problem with the jssor slider.
I get an overlap on the right side which also gives a horizontal scrollbar.

I think it's because of the scalewidth percentage, if i lower this percentage with 0.03 it looks good. I am using a body padding of 10px on the left and right, so that on mobile there is breathing room.

I think i need a new 'formula' to intergrate the padding's in the calculation of the scalewidth.

```
            if (bodyWidth)
                jssor_slider1.$ScaleWidth(Math.min(bodyWidth, 619)); //set max width for the page or container
```

Sadly i am a complete programming noob so i am hoping that someone can help me fix this because i really like the slider but i need the images to be pushed 10px from both sides (by the body)

Comment: Can you provide more of the code so we can reproduce it to try and fix it?  Also, possibly provide a screenshot of the overlap with the horizontal scrollbar?

Comment: @UncleRico I have taken two screenshots: 
The first is without body padding -> http://i.imgur.com/6IIGbPI.jpg

The second is with the body padding, so it forces the whole container/site inwards 10px on both sides, but then the image/container is too large and overlaps -> http://i.imgur.com/pIEsNyC.jpg

<div id="slider1_container" style="position: relative; top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 619px; height: 432px;">
    <!-- Slides Container -->        
       
  
<div u="slides" style="cursor: pointer; position: absolute; overflow: hidden; left: 0px; top: 0px; width: 619px; margin: 0; height: 432px;">

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As there is 10 + 10 = 20 padding in width,

```
if (bodyWidth)
    jssor_slider1.$ScaleWidth(Math.min(bodyWidth - 20, 619));
```

Comment: I feel silly lol, so simple. Thank you very much! :)

Great slider!